# Linq to Sql Create Database Foreign Key Problem

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ to SQL in project. I am using DataContext.CreateDatabase() method to create database.

There is one Master table having ID as OK

Other tables are referring to this ID as FK. **I have set the Update and Delete role to Cascade in FK**. So whenever record from master table is removed all the referencing records are automatically removed from all child tables..

If i delete database and start my application which checks the existence of database at start up. It creates database successful. But problem is in created FK. Update and Delete role are Set to **No Action** instead of Cascade.. **Because of this i have to change all the FK Update and Delete specification to Cascade manually**

Does anyone facing this problem? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DeleteOnNull=true` to perform deletions on Association's.

Note that `DeleteOnNull` isn't quite the same thing as cascade on delete as this deletion is done in c# code and not in the database - see this blog for details http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/05/11/linq-to-sql-tips-4-use-deleteonnull-if-you-want-to-delete-object-with-null-fk.aspx